# Openvpn (ipfire) net-to-net connection gets wrong IP address from some pool

Tags: linux, openvpn, linux-networking

I try to set up a connection over the internet between two ipfire routers, having OpenVPN installed on both. r3 is the server, r1 the client.

It almost works. First, the "server" is started: here are what i think are the most relevant log lines:

```
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23717]: OpenVPN 2.3.18 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [MH] [IPv6] built on Nov  3 2017
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23717]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017, LZO 2.09
[...]
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
[...]
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1400
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.0.13.1 peer 10.0.13.2
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: /sbin/ip route add 10.0.13.0/24 via 10.0.13.2
[...]
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: Listening for incoming TCP connection on [undef]
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: TCPv4_SERVER link local (bound): [undef]
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [undef]
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.0.13.4 size=62, ipv6=0
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: MULTI: TCP INIT maxclients=100 maxevents=104
Jul  5 18:44:24 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: Initialization Sequence Completed
```

The first problem arises : why `IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.0.13.4` ? I did not set that anywhere.

Then i start the client on r1 and here the logs on r3 :

```
Jul  5 19:25:50 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]<r1'IP>:1194
[...]
Jul  5 19:25:51 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: <r1'IP>:1194 WARNING: 'ifconfig' is present in remote config but missing in local config, remote='ifconfig 10.0.13.1 10.0.13.2'
[...]
Jul  5 19:25:51 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: r1.FQDN/<r1'IP>:1194 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.0.13.6, IPv6=(Not enabled)
Jul  5 19:25:51 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: r1.FQDN/<r1'IP>:1194 MULTI: Learn: 10.0.13.6 -> r1.FQDN/<r1'IP>:1194
Jul  5 19:25:51 r3 openvpnserver[23718]: r1.FQDN/<r1'IP>:1194 MULTI: primary virtual IP for r1.FQDN/<r1'IP>:1194: 10.0.13.6
```

So i don't get it: base IP is 10.0.13.4 (don't know where it comes from) and now the peer IP is... `MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.0.13.6` ?

At the same the link on tun0 is between 10.0.13.1 and 10.0.13.2.

So routes are broken and despite the fact the connexion is established and authenticated, I can't route the traffic between the two internals subnets (192.168.1.0/24 and .2.0/24 for that matters).

What is wrong ? Shouldn't the IP on both sides of the VPN be 10.0.13.1 and 10.0.13.2 ?

Where do the @IP 13.4 or 13.6 come from ?

Answer (score 0):

While i still don't understand where those addresses are coming from, someone on the OpenVPN support forum told me to use the `topology subnet` option in the config.

The default and NOT RECOMMENDED value of this option (see https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/master/sample/sample-config-files/server.conf) is `net30` for the support of some old windows clients.

(Anything relating to windows leads to unexpected results, so i'm not suprised anymore)

Yet IPFire has no option to configure this, so i guess it is supposed to work without that, but that's another question.